# Unable to access mysql from jpa after Catalina update

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, macos-catalina

My jpa application was working fine (in fact, my 2 jpa applications) since I update my mac to Catalina (and restart it, of course).

Since then I got

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

But from mySQL Workbench I can access my databases with no problem.

I've tried to reinstall mysql, even using brew to do it. Nothing works.
I changed nothing on my persistence.xml file nor my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyProject" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="MyPassword"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My mysql version is 8.0.19.

Thank you!

**Next day update (28/4):**

By now, I have:
1) Added this line to my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
```

As I got a new error...

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

2) Followed this instructions to set root password:
https://medium.com/@aungzanbaw/how-to-reset-root-user-password-in-mysql-8-0-a5c328d098a8

Now my new error is

```
Connection refused
```

**Next next day update (29/4):**

Today I stoped and started mysql from terminal:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server start
```

I then I got a new error

```
The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

Let's continue my investigation!

Following this question: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/configurar-zona-horaria-jdbc-driver-java/48946?newreg=494e1840d4404575a81dc4ec10200266

I modified persistence.xml:

So I got a

```
Table 'myschema.mytable' doesn't exist
```

error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it, not sure how... probably restarting from comand line.

Here my final persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyProject" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="MyPassword"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Using MySQL**8**Dialect is necessary to be able to create the tables without that error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
```